# Find corresponding solid to a given shell

Tags: python, python-2.5

The problem I am working on is CAE / FEM related and can be summarized as followed:

I'm reading a file that contains nodes (points in 3D, defined by a node number and X / Y / Z coordinates), triangular shell elements (defined by an element number and 3 nodes) and tetrahedral solid elements (defined by an element number and 4 nodes). The data is stored in 3 dictioniaries:

```
nodes  = {'Node_ID' : [X, Y, Z]};
shells = {'Shell_ID': ['Node_ID_1', 'Node_ID_2', 'Node_ID_3']};
solids = {'Solid_ID': ['Node_ID_1', 'Node_ID_2', 'Node_ID_3', 'Node_ID_4']};
```

Every shell has a corresponding solid with same nodes:

```
for shell_k, shell_v in shells.iteritems():
  for solid_k, solid_v in solids.iteritems():
    if((shell_v[0] in solid_v) and (shell_v[1] in solid_v) and (shell_v[2] in solid_v)):
      # This is true for one combination of shell and solid
```

Python needs for this approximately 100 seconds (number of shells is about 12,000, number of solids is about 40,000, therefore the if-query has to be performed 480,000,000 times. Is it possible to reduce the complexity from O(mn) to something faster with small effort?

**Edit:** Some examples of nodes, shells, solids:

**Nodes:**

```
 # In file:

 2504888, 190.05780, 101.70673, 320.68655
 2504889, 187.96325, 101.82080, 322.86340
 2504890, 192.14670, 103.65783, 320.42405
 2504891, 188.52980, 105.40890, 320.94880
 2504892, 190.05215, 103.77190, 322.60090

 # As dict:

 nodes[2504888] = [190.05780, 101.70673, 320.68655];
 nodes[2504889] = [187.96325, 101.82080, 322.86340];
 nodes[2504890] = [192.14670, 103.65783, 320.42405];
 nodes[2504891] = [188.52980, 105.40890, 320.94880];
 nodes[2504892] = [190.05215, 103.77190, 322.60090];
```

**Shells:**

```
 # In file:

 227, 3866603, 3862785, 3862784
 228, 3866603, 3862784, 3866559
 229, 3866585, 3866603, 3866559
 230, 3866635, 3866603, 3866585
 231, 3866208, 3866635, 3866585

 # As dict:

 shells[227] = [3866603, 3862785, 3862784];
 shells[228] = [3866603, 3862784, 3866559];
 shells[229] = [3866585, 3866603, 3866559];
 shells[230] = [3866635, 3866603, 3866585];
 shells[231] = [3866208, 3866635, 3866585];
```

**Solids:**

```
 # In file:

 3622889, 4130281, 4130283, 4126885, 4126884
 3622890, 4130281, 4126885, 4129084, 4126884
 3622891, 4130281, 4129084, 4129080, 4126884
 3622892, 4129080, 4129084, 4129083, 4126884
 3622895, 4129080, 4129083, 4129079, 4126884

 # As dict:

 solids[3622889] = [4130281, 4130283, 4126885, 4126884];
 solids[3622890] = [4130281, 4126885, 4129084, 4126884];
 solids[3622891] = [4130281, 4129084, 4129080, 4126884];
 solids[3622892] = [4129080, 4129084, 4129083, 4126884];
 solids[3622895] = [4129080, 4129083, 4129079, 4126884];
```

An example for a shell / solid pair would be:

```
# Nodes:
3854247, 19.82965, 133.65520, 203.52418
3867556, 18.85539, 132.60338, 203.77993
3866448, 18.66001, 134.38551, 204.89977
3867528, 18.34272, 134.38552, 203.95146

# Shell:
415734, 3867556, 3866448, 3867528

# Solid:
3478898, 3867528, 3866448, 3867556, 3854247
```

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show at least three examples of `shells` and `solids`.

Comment: I expected to see e.g. Node: `2504888` in Shells or Shells.Node: `3866603` in Solides [...]. Makes no sense to me or bad examples?

Comment: Bad example, I just copied the first five nodes, shells and solids...

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Is it possible to reduce the complexity from O(mn) to something faster with small effort?

---

> **Note**: Your Python Version is outdated, couldn't use your notation.

1. To simplify the `if condition` using `set()`

   ```
   for shell_k in shells:
       for solid_k in solids:
           if set(shells[shell_k]).issubset(set(solids[solid_k])):
               # This is true for one combination of shell and solid
   ```

   Or, Precondition Values are of Type `set()` to eliminate Type Casting:

   ```
   for shell_k in shells_set:
       for solid_k in solids_set:
           if shells_set[shell_k].issubset(solids_set[solid_k]):
               # This is true for one combination of shell and solid
   ```
2. Solution using NumPy

   > NumPy v1.13 Manual: [**numpy.in1d**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)
   >
   > ```
   > numpy.in1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=False, invert=False)[source]
   > ```
   >
   > Test whether each element of a 1-D array is also present in a second array.
   >   Returns a boolean array the same length as ar1 that is True where an element of ar1 is in ar2 and False otherwise.

   Preconditioned Data as numpy.ndarray's

   ```
   shells(4, 3): [[3866448 3867528 3867556]
                   [3862784 3862785 3866603]
                   [4126884 4126885 4130283]
                   [3862784 3866559 3866603]]

   solids(4, 4): [[3854247 3866448 3867528 3867556]
                  [4126884 4126885 4130281 4130283]
                  [4126884 4126885 4129084 4130281]
                  [4126883 4126885 4129084 4130282]]

   solids_id:[3478898 3478899 3478900 3478901]
   ```

   ---

   ```
   import numpy as np
   # Get a (4,4) numpy Mask from Shells in Solids
   solids_in1d = np.in1d(solids, n_shells).reshape(solids.shape)

   # Get Array of y Index of Masked Solides with 3 Nodes
   solids_idx = np.where(np.sum(solids_in1d, axis=1) == 3)[0]

   # Print Solids - Show ID and only the 3 Solid Nodes
   for y in solids_idx:
       print('Solids ID:{} Nodes:{}'.format(solids_id[y], solids[y][solids_in1d[y]]))
   ```

   > **Output**:
   >
   > ```
   > Solids ID:3478898 Nodes:[3866448 3867528 3867556]
   > Solids ID:3478899 Nodes:[4126884 4126885 4130283]
   > ```
3. Alternatives
   Using [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin) instead of `numpy.in1d`
   Couldn't try it as it's new in version 1.13.0.

   I could imagin that `pandas` could handle this.

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - numpy:1.12.1***